# Get Magento time via Javascript

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax, timezone

I need to create a CMS page that will update information at specific times. E.g.: If now is 1pm, the page will display information X. If now is 2pm, the page will display information Y.

I created a PHP file with this code `echo Mage::getModel('core/date')->date()` that returns my current date and time, but if I try to call this via AJAX to update my page, I got a "Forbidden error".

I read that to call PHP file using AJAX in Magento I need to create a new module (references [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27121520/link-a-php-file-to-an-ajax-request-in-magento) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908466/calling-a-php-file-from-ajax)), but since I never created a module before and this page will be used just for 1 day; I don't think is worthy creating a new module (I am assuming would take me some time to do that).

Any ideas of how I could dynamically get my Magento time zone to use in an HTML page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using a time API (https://timezonedb.com/) and setting my AJAX request to this API instead of using Magento functions.